# Oracle SQL | Making a date field from two separate fields

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How would I make a single date field using these two fields?

So if I had a table with this:

```
MONTH        YEAR
2            2013
4            2012
2            2012
```

How would I combine the month and the year to make a field in that looks like this...

```
DATE
2013-02
2012-04
2012-02
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, I would just use concatenation and `lpad()`:

```
select (year || '-' || lpad(month, 2, '0') ) as date
```